# Relation between bounds.extents and trasform.localScale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the `bounds.extents` to represent the radius of a sprite in Unity. In my simulation I am changing the size of the sprite using `transform.localScale`. When I want to spawn new sprites I want to spawn them so that the radius won't exceed my ground (represented as a plane). Thus I am making sure that the new sprite is not spawned within a range of `bounds.extents` to the edge of the plane. But when the sprites reaches their maximum radius they exceed the edge of the plane. So my question is, what is the relation between `bounds.extents` and `transform.localScale`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that the radius you allow the sprites to be placed in is less than the extents of the plane and the half the size of the sprite. because when you place the sprite on the edge of the radius, the center of it is on the borders of the plane, so half of it is outside it. Did I understand the problem correctly? 
As for the relation, the `bounds.extents` describes **half the size** of the sprite in units, while `transform.localscale` is the scale relative to the object's parent's scale. It is also an indication of the current size compared to the original size of the sprite, it doesn't indicate the size in units.

So assuming the parent's scale is 1:

bounds.extents = (original bounds.extents) * transform.localScale

Comment: I want to place the sprite on the plane so that the outer edge does not exceed the plane edges. For example, when the `bounds.extents` = 14 the `transform.localScale` = 100 (for both x and y axis).

Comment: I'm not sure if you should be concerned about the scale, just make sure that the position of the sprite is placed in a position which is < (plane's extents - sprite's extents) 

So for example say that the plane's extents is  -100 and 100 for the x axis and  -200 and 200 for the y-axis...and the sprite's extents  is 50 (so that means 50 from its center)  so you will have to make sure that the sprite is placed as far as  -50 and 50 x and -150 and 150 y. 
Hope that works for you.